# Create a list inside a tuple inside a list of all numbers paired with an integer

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list like this:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 9)]
```

That I need to convert to a tuple that looks like this:

```
[(0, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [4, 6, 7, 9])]
```

This is the code I have:

```
friends = open(file_name).read().splitlines()
network = []
friends = [tuple(int(y) for y in x.split(' ')) for x in friends]
return friends
```

Comment: Use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse the list from the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
s = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 9)]
final_data = [(a, [i[-1] for i in list(b)]) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(s, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

Output:

```
[(0, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [4, 6, 7, 9])]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you ask for but from the kind of output you're looking for please let, me suggest you using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), it is super readable and efficient,

```
from collections import defaultdict

some_list = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 9)]

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in some_list:
    d[k].append(v)
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 6, 7, 9]})
```

Answer (score 0):

a 'one liner' nested list comprehension, with a line break

```
tpls = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 9)]  

[(k, [tp[1] for tp in tpls if tp[0] == k])
 for k in set([*zip(*tpls)][0])]

Out[11]: [(0, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [4, 6, 7, 9])]
```

`[*zip(*tpls)]` is an idiom that 'transposes' the sub iterable

giving `[(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9)]`

so `set([*zip(*tpls)][0])` is `set((0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1))`

which gives the unique items in the 1st position of the tuples in `tpls`: `{0, 1}`

which the outer `for k in ...`  iterates over, providing `k` to the list comp inside the result tuple
`[tp[1] for tp in tpls if tp[0] == k]`